# lodash - Remove columns from datatable (2D matrix) if all values are null

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a 2D matrix like this one where the first row is the columns names and other rows are values.

```
var datatable = [
  ["a", "b",   "c",   "d"],  //first row are columns names
  [ 1,   0,     null,  3 ],  //other rows are values
  [ 6,   null,  null,  8 ]
];
```

I would like to remove columns when all values are `null` as the expected result below:

```
var datatable = [
  ["a", "b",   "d"],  //first row are columns names
  [ 1,   0,     3 ],  //other rows are values
  [ 6,   null,  8 ]
];
```

The numbers of rows and columns can vary. If there is a compact and fast way to achieve it with lodash that's perfect.

Comment: because there was a value in the second array

Comment: because all values of the column must be null to be removed

Comment: The third column has `c` in it. Why was that removed?

Comment: because the first row is the columns names and they can never be null. It's like an Excel table if you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have my approach using `map()`, `filter()` and `some()`.

```js
var datatable = [
  ["a", "b",   "c",   "d"],
  [ 1,   0,     null,  3 ],
  [ 6,   null,  null,  8 ]
];

let res = datatable.map(
  x => x.filter((_, idx) => datatable.slice(1).some(arr => arr[idx] !== null))
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get first the columns with all `null` values and then filter the rows.

```js
var datatable = [["a", "b", "c", "d"], [1, 0, null, 3], [6, null, null, 8]],
    cols = datatable
        .slice(1)                                                   // omit header
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => r[i] || v !== null), []);

datatable = datatable.map(a => a.filter((_, i) => cols[i]));

console.log(datatable);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.flow()` that creates a function that transposes the array using `_.unzip()`, rejects arrays that have all `null` values, and then unzips the array back to the original form:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, unzip, reject, tail, every, isNull } = _; // convert to imports

const fn = flow(
  unzip,
  pr(reject, flow(tail, pr(every, isNull))),
  unzip,
);

const datatable = [
  ["a", "b",   "c",   "d"],  //first row are columns names
  [ 1,   0,     null,  3 ],  //other rows are values
  [ 6,   null,  null,  8 ]
];

const result = fn(datatable);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the terser lodash/fp solution:

```js
const { flow, unzip, reject, tail, every, isNull } = _; // convert to imports

const fn = flow(
  unzip,
  reject(flow(
    tail,
    every(isNull)
  )),
  unzip,
);

const datatable = [
  ["a", "b",   "c",   "d"],  //first row are columns names
  [ 1,   0,     null,  3 ],  //other rows are values
  [ 6,   null,  null,  8 ]
];

const result = fn(datatable);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: You could explain each function call and its purpose, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly longer code, but similar idea.

```js
var datatable = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  [1, 0, null, 3],
  [6, null, null, 8]
];

/* first create a simple key val map as {a:[1,6],b:[0,null] etc to weed out the keys with all nulls */

let keyValMap = datatable.reduce((acc,arr,index) => {
 if(index===0) {
  arr.forEach(key => {
   if(!acc[key])
    acc[key]=[]
  });
 } else {
  Object.keys(acc).map((key,index) => acc[key].push(arr[index])); 
 }
 return acc;
},{});

// now extract only those keys that do not have every element as null
let validKeys = Object.keys(keyValMap).filter(key => !keyValMap[key].every(i => i===null));

// pivot back from keyValMap the values based on validKeys
let updatedDataTable = [validKeys,  ...validKeys.map(key =>  keyValMap[key]).reduce((acc,val)=>{
  val.forEach((elem,i) => {
    if(!acc[i]) acc[i]=[];
    acc[i].push(elem)
  });
  return acc;
 },[]) ]

console.log(updatedDataTable);
```